# What is the default 'backup' user for?

Tags: 10.04, server, backup

I am setting up multiple-machine backup plan and I was hoping to use a user called 'backup' on each machine as the backup destination.

My problem is, there is already a user called 'backup' on my machine.

What is it for, and can I hijack it for my own purposes?

```
root@frodo:~# useradd backup
useradd: user 'backup' already exists
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can confirm it's in a default installation, see the `/usr/share/base-passwd/passwd.master` file provided by the `base-passwd` package.

According to the documentation from that package, it is used for backup accounts without requiring full root permissions (which is available at `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.txt.gz`, `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html` and [online](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/base-passwd/-/blob/master/doc/users-and-groups.sgml)):

> backup
>
> Presumably so backup/restore responsibilities can be locally delegated to
> someone without full root permissions?
>
> HELP: Is that right? Amanda reportedly uses this, details?

Note the keyword **locally**, for remote backups you [have to enable a login shell first](https://bugs.debian.org/771925). You are free to use it for your own purposes, but note the above guide lines. Do not grant `sudo` policies for example that would allow the backup user to escalate its privileges to root.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not really answer the question, whether it is ok to hijack that user or not.

Comment: @ali See edit, it is probably fine to use it for your own purposes. A quick scan through [Debian Code Search: `backup path:debian/ -path:debian/patches/ -path:debian/changelog`](https://codesearch.debian.net/perpackage-results/backup%20path%3Adebian%2F%20-path%3Adebian%2Fpatches%2F%20-path%3Adebian%2Fchangelog/2/page_0) did not show anything related to the backup user (I stopped at page 8).

Comment: Slightly concerning that the documenters (still) don't know what it's for either.